# MEAN.JS: How to create of 1 model that requires another

Tags: mean, meanjs

Notice: I am new to MEAN and every single part of what makes MEAN up.

In reference to the default configuration of [MEANJS](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) and the example module `Articles`. I have created another model called `Program`.

I know how to add other fields or properties to a model to be able to create and edit accordingly, but I haven't a clue when that new property is a reference to another model.

Without getting into the details of what a `Program` is, I want to modify the existing create and edit pages for `Articles` to require the user to specify, from a dropdown, which `Program` it belongs to.

I have already updated the `Articles` schema

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  program: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Program',
    required: 'Program cannot be blank'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps you need to follow:

1. Make sure there's a list function in your Program server side controller (program.server.controller.js)

   ```
    TheProgram = mongoose.model('Program')

    ...
    /**
     * List of programs
     */
    exports.list = function (req, res) {
        console.log('ProgramController.server.list');
        TheProgram.find().exec(function (err, events) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.json(programs);
            }
        });
    };
   ```

2. Create the proper policy(programs.server.policy.js, omitted here) and routes for program on the server side (program.server.routes.js)

   ```
    module.exports = function (app) {
        // program collection routes
        app.route('/api/programs').all(programPolicy.isAllowed)
            .get(programs.list);
   ```
3. Create the client side angular Event service (programs.client.service.js omitted here) that should be injected in the controller and create the controller (programs.client.controller.js) that gets the program list from server side:

   ```
        // Find a list of Programs
        $scope.find = function () {
            $log.info('executing ProgramController.$scope.find');
            self.programs = Programs.query();
        };
   ```
4. Then load the program list on the page:

   ```
    <select ng-options="program in programs" ng-model="selectedProgram"></select>
   ```

I have omitted some required code but this should provide a good start.